# Azure- Getting (AuthorizationFailed) even with owner role assigned to my account

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

When I run `az aks get-credentials --name project --resource-group project-rg`, I get the following error:
[image]

but I have owner access level in the resource group:
[image]

I've tried 1. logging out and logging in. 2. `az account set --subscription guid2`. 3. checked if I have the right permissions (checked **Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterAdminCredential/action**
Neither has worked. Any suggestions?[image]

Solution- turns out I didn't run the `az account set --subscription <guid>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...Turns out I needed to set the cluster subscription using `az account set --subscription <guid>`

Answer (score 0):

You would need the specific permission at the cluster level to be able to run the get-credentials command.
The permission is:
**Microsoft.ContainerService/managedCluster/listClusterUserCredential/action**

This permission is usually included in the following default roles:

- **Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role**
- **Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role**

If you give yourself one of these permissions, you should be authorised to run the get-credentials command.

Comment: I'm been given the owner role and have verified that I have permission for Microsoft.ContainerService/managedCluster/listClusterUserCredential/action... (added screenshot in question)